# Handling of pluralia tantum in glossaries

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, plural

I have a term that does not exist in singular form (i.e., a plurale tantum) that I would like to abbreviate like ordinary acronyms. How should such a thing be handled properly in glossaries (if at all)? Probably the best thing would be to make the singular form of it raise an error so that only the plural forms can be used. Is there a viable way to do that (i.e., without redefining any of the glossaries functions)?

The term in question is *single-event multiple upsets (SEMUs)*.
I could of course simply define it normally (i.e. with a wrong singular) with `\newacronym{SEMU}{SEMU}{single-event multiple upset}` and then always use the plural forms like `\acp{SEMU}`... and that's what I do for now. But I was wondering if there is a better way.

I tried with the following and that works fine while referencing it in the text but fails to print the glossary at the end, of course... I presume because `\glossentry` non-surprisingly uses the singular...

`\newacronym[longplural={single-event multiple upsets},shortplural={SEMUs}]{SEMU}{\errmessage{SEMUs is always plural}}{}`

A MWE that shows the latter problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomain,acronym,shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newacronym[longplural={single-event multiple upsets},shortplural={SEMUs}]{SEMU}{\errmessage{SEMUs is always plural}}{}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\acp{SEMU}

\printglossary[type=acronym]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would just define the singular form to be plural and the plural form to be the same

Answer (score 1):

If you're not gonna fill in the blanks for singular definitions, you can use the plural definitions both for singular and plural. An attempt of solution using `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\PluraleTantum}{o m m m}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{%
        \newacronym[longplural={#4},shortplural={#3}]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }{%
        \newacronym[longplural={#4},shortplural={#3},#1]{#2}{#3}{#4}%
    }
}
\PluraleTantum{SEMU}{SEMUs}{single-event multiple upsets}
```

As `\PluraleTantum` does not redefine anything, `\acp` and other `glossaries` commands still work. Unless you have more fine-grained needs, the code above will work.